# Is iPod docking station just a USB with a different connector?

Tags: usb, ipod, iphone

Let's say I'm building a device with an iPod docking connector. Can I use standard software for USB on the device side? Are there any special considerations?

The device is supposed to play audio. Charging is good to have but optional.

Comment: There are many models of iPod and several different dock connectors. What precicely are you attempting to learn / accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engadget has a great tutorial on how to create a custom iPod docking station, along with system configurations, etc.

Hope this helps:

[How-To: iPod docking station/configuration](http://www.engadget.com/2006/04/18/how-to-design-your-own-ipod-super-dock-part-1/)